# General design approach to LiFePO4 charging

Tags: charging, lifepo4

I'm trying to design a charging circuit for a 12V 120Ah LiFePO4 battery pack from a DC generator. Part of the project that the battery powers contains a Pi, and I'm not sure whether it's clever to delegate the control components of charging (battery diagnostics to follow the correct charging curve) to the Pi and provide the necessary peripherals, or if it's smarter to just invest in a charge controller chip. I've read how important precise voltage measurements are in avoiding under- or over-loading lithium batteries, so that may factor in with sourcing good enough ADCs and such. I plan on using MPPT to maximise efficiency, if that's relevant.

Is there any general wisdom for this sort of thing? I realise it's a somewhat unusual case.

Thanks!

Comment: If "Pi" refers to Rasp Pi then it's unsuitable for professional use in general and real-time systems in particular. You don't want any software-generated PWM in a battery charger and you want real-time characteristics. There is absolutely no reason why you wouldn't use a BMS IC for this, particularly if you have larger charger currents and rely on a NTC thermistor. For scenarios where you would use your own custom MCU in place of a pre-made BMS, you wouldn't use a Linux PC but rather something cheap that fits the spec.

Comment: The answers to your questions would require us to have a good knowledge of your skill and knowledge level and are a little to broad for this forum. Try breaking your question down into a number of answerable questions. e.g What methodology should I use to get good cell voltage measurements when charging a LiFePO4 battery.

Comment: Consider if your software screws up - then I hear that LiFePO4 is fairly safe and won't explode, but you could still ruin the battery. Is that a good risk?

Comment: At the very minimum, you should use a dedicated hard-real-time microcontroller for the actual BMS bit.  Interface to it from the Pi if you need to, but don't put anything "Mission Critical" on a Pi.  They're great hobby tools, but they're incredibly unreliable in my experience.  Also, battery management is a big topic.  While I'm usually in favor of "DIY everything", this is an area where a dedicated chip is well worth it.  IMHO, the best wisdom in this case is "don't try it at home".  (If you do / did though, I'm curious to see how it turns out!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General wisdom? Sure: A very wise man once said "Do or do not. There is no try."

Don't try to do anything with a 120Ah battery. Don't try to make a charger. Ether you have sufficient knowledge to build a ***safe*** charger, or you don't. If you don't prosess that knowledge a battery charger is not the kind of project you *try* to do.